# How can I update a UI progressbar or backgroundworker from code in a separate class?

Tags: c#, class, progress-bar, backgroundworker

Somewhat new to C# but I have a major problem with getting these things to work because if my background worker is running a long process by using a method from another class, then that class has no access to the background worker in order to update the progress.

For instance:

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bgArgs args = e.Argument as bgArgs;
    MyClass objMyClass = new MyClass();

    MyClass.MyMethod(strValue, args.Option);

    //Do something based on return value of long process.
}
```

If I try to update bgWorker from the class "MyClass", it cannot "see" bgWorker, it doesn't exist in the context of the class, it's in the UI class because in Visual Studio, that's where you drag it from the toolbox.

The only way I've gotten it to work is to pass the whole UI form to the class, which creates other problems when trying to access that class from anywhere but the main form. From there I just update the progress bar manually via ProgressBar1.PerformStep() as it runs through the loops.

Also, I've already changed the modifier on my progress bar to internal, so it's not that the class doesn't see the progress bar.

I might be able to pass the bgworker by itself to the class through the method, but that just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

I think your architecture needs revising here.  The background worker is for running operations in the background, like out-of-sight-out-of-mind.  While it is running, you can accept feedback from it by observing the BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event, which will help you increment your progress bar with PerformStep().  However, you shouldn't attempt to alter the BackgroundWorker while it is running.  This gets you into [Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) issues, which I'm not sure you really want :)  You see, the BackgroundWorker uses a different thread to perform its operations when it runs, so changing it while running means you have to access the thread it is performing its work upon.  This gets ugly.  It is best to just give it a method to execute, let it run, check in on its ProgressChanged, and wait for it to finish.

Comment: How do I check on the progress changed?  For example, the method loops through a variable number of sessions on a Citrix farm to find a specific user.  As it begins, I have it set the bar maximum to the total number of sessions, then begin the loop, as it loops through it steps the progress bar up by one.  It's very accurate, but how would the bgworker know how far the progress is?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly you probably need to make a method that can access the UI progressBar despite the source thread. The below will do just that saving you from blowing up the application when you try to set the value.

```
private delegate void UpdateProgressBarCallback(int barValue);
private void UpdateProgressBarHandler(int barValue)
{
    if (this.progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
        this.BeginInvoke(new UpdateProgressBarCallback(this.UpdateProgressBarHandler), new object[]{ barValue });
    else
    {
        // change your bar
        this.progressBar1.Value = barValue;
    }
}
```

[see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx ]

Then you just call UpdateProgressBar(value); (likewise, if you want this to step you can adjust the arguments/way the method operates)

Next you can go about this a few ways: You can make your background worker (since it's already in another class) event driven and then attach progress changes and update the UI; or you can pass a delegate to the thread workers as a reference so it knows where to adjust the UI.

Comment and leave me a direction to go and I'll see if I can help you (and confirm I understand the question).

Comment: When using this pattern use [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx) instead of Invoke. The Control class has a exeption to the BeginXxxx needs a EndXxxx rule (see the remarks section of the MSDN article I linked). This will cause the begin call not to block and not hold up your second thread.

Comment: Touché. That's what i get for typing it up ad-hoc. But thanks for the reference, I'll update the code in my post.

Comment: It's not that I can't access the progress bar from a separate thread, it's that I can't access the background worker from a separate class.  The class method is what is doing all the work.  Once the background worker passes the work to that method, the method has no clue where it came from and thus cannot do a bgWorker.ReportProgress().

Comment: Then why don't you add a construct that accepts backgroundWorker as an argument and pass the sender in with the construct when you declare it? MyClass objMyClass = new MyClass(sender);

Comment: Because then I can't declare that class from anywhere other than where the background worker is and I can't declare that class out in the class constructor either, which I do for all the other classes because there are so many buttons that call the same class to do different things.  It's an app for the helpdesk that does a lot of various administrative tasks automatically.  Maybe what I'm trying to do is impossible.

Comment: How about using a Singleton for the administration class?